# How to read an actual price of another currency pair, not available directly in a [ Strategy Tester ] - for a Multi-Currency Strategy?

Tags: mql4, metatrader4, mql5

In the Internet, across many boards one can read that it is impossible to make use of **`MarketInfo()`** function in the <kbd>Strategy Tester</kbd>. It's the limitation of the platform.

I haven't found on the web any workaround for this. However, since the need is the mother of invention, and my need was to make **`USDJPY`** market decisions with EA that depends on the state of **`EURUSD`** market I've found the workaround ( which is good enough for me ). I use **`iMA()`** with a period of one, and `M1` resolution.

> `iMA( "EURUSD", PERIOD_M1, 1, 0, MODE_SMA, PRICE_MEDIAN, i )`

**The question is**:
 since <kbd>MetaTrader</kbd> is able to calculate Moving Average for another currency ( which is surely based on the actual price of the pair! ),
**`Q1:` why can't one has access to the current value : directly?**

And **a follow-up question:**
**`Q2:`** Is there any other ( more accurate ) workaround for this limitation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**REASON**: The reason to that question is because of "Tick". Because a "tick" in one currency happens independently from the "tick" of another currency, it is not possible to accurately determine the Price of another currency basing on the current "Tick" of one currency.  The `iMA` is calculated using the OHLC of the M1 candle, and not the actual "Tick" (which is not the same as "Tick" data).

**Rephrase**: Let's say we are on USDJPY, and this "tick" happens at 12:00:00.210 (12mid-night at the 210th millisecond). When that "tick" happens, the `start()` event gets triggered. In that function, we look for Bid of EURUSD. However, there is no "Tick" for EURUSD as of that time (the USDJPY and EURUSD do not "tick" at the same time), thus it is not possible to determine the exact price of EURUSD at-that-point-in-time.

There is no workaround because it is impossible to determine the price on the "Tick" level because MQL4's `datetime` variable is an `integer` and accurate only to the seconds, and the HistoryCenter>Export are OHLC only.

Your `iMA()` is as good as it gets.

Answer (score -1):

**`Q1:`** was well served by @JosephLee + there is **one more option (ref. below)**
**`Q2:`** deserves a word:

---

### Yes, there is a workaround.

While <kbd>MetaTrader Terminal 4</kbd> has many weaknesses, not worth one's time to spend time here, there are also nice things one can do with it.

Some five years ago, there was a project-need to integrate a distributed-processing for MT4, so as to circumvent it's given weaknesses.

That happened. This way you can benefit from a distributed-processing framework and **can have down to a few `nanoseconds` ( latency-wise ) exact prices of all instruments at will** ( based on a remote `QUOTE`-stream processing ) **independently of your** localhost **`MT4.graph _Symbol`**

Do not hesitate to ask more
&
welcome to the
**Worlds of MQL4**

---

### *New-*`MQL4.56789` has an `iClose()` functionality for multi-currency

> Returns `Close` price value for the bar of specified symbol with timeframe and shift.

```
double  iClose(     string           symbol,          // symbol 
                    int              timeframe,       // timeframe 
                    int              shift            // shift 
                    );
```

> **Parameters**
> **`symbol`**
> [in] Symbol name. `NULL` means the current symbol.
> **`timeframe`**
> [in] Timeframe. It can be any of `ENUM_TIMEFRAMES` enumeration values. `0` means the current chart timeframe.
> **`shift`**
> [in] Index of the value taken from the indicator buffer (shift relative to the current bar the given amount of periods ago).
> **`Returned value`**
> `Close` price value for the bar of specified `symbol` with `timeframe` and `shift`. If local history is empty (not loaded), function returns `0`. To check errors, one has to call the **`GetLastError()`** function.

Be cautious on it's use in <kbd>**`StrategyTester`**</kbd> with a due care taken on error-handling the cases the history data is not in local database and a need to provide a remedy-handling procedures for remote-retrieval from server appears.

```
Print( "A first date in the history for the EURUSD on the [MT4SERVER] = ",
       (datetime) SeriesInfoInteger( "EURUSD", 0, SERIES_SERVER_FIRSTDATE )
       );
```

Similarly need to provide some measures for cases the above indicated need **`ERR_HISTORY_WILL_UPDATED`** appears while the remote-server is not online / market is closed **`ERR_MARKET_CLOSED`** / the requested date is already before the **`SERIES_SERVER_FIRSTDATE`** etc.

In a corner-case, there is always a possibility to create a special-setup with step-wise updating both local `CCY_PAIR` and a `REMOTE_CCY_PAIR` totally independent of a Broker-side equipment status.

All these are important aspects of this new MQL4 feature.